# Is the ThreadFactory generated by TheadFactoryBuilder thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, threadpool, guava

Suppose I have the following code and makePool can be called by multiple threads. I'm using [ThreadFactoryBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html#setNameFormat-java.lang.String-) to make sure the threads have a unique name.

```
private final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat(
                    "MyBusinessClass-%d").build();

public ExecutorService makePool() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, threadFactory);
}
```

or do I have to assume the pool is not thread safe, and have to do something like:

```
private static final AtomicLong poolCount = new AtomicLong(0L);

public ExecutorService makePool() {
    private final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat(
        "MyBusinessClass- " + poolCount.incrementAndGet() + "-%d").build();
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, threadFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reading of the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/10.0.1/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.java#6406006219309982427) (Guava 10.0.1) is that it is thread safe, so long as the backing thread factory is thread safe.  In your code, the backing thread factory will be an instance of `Executors.DefaultThreadFactory` which is thread-safe.

Note that none of this is *specified* ... as far as I can see..  However, the way that these classes are coded says to me that they are thread-safe *by design*.  The mutable components of the respective objects consist of counters implemented as atomics, and thread creation / starting has a *happens-before*.

Comment: I don't think I'm using the default thread factory if I provide a name format.

Comment: Check the source code. I think you are using it.  The only scenario where you won't use the default thread factory is if you called `setThreadFactory` on the `ThreadFactoryBuilder` object.

Comment: I looked up the source. They are using an atomic long for the count and using that in the anonymous thread factory they return, so it's thread safe. Please add this reference to your answer: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/10.0.1/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.java#146

Comment: @Joseph - My answer already links to the source code.  See the hyperlink on the phrase "source code"?

Comment: I see that it does. Add might have been the wrong word. I meant replace. My link goes directly to the .build() method.

Comment: The relevant code is not all at that point.  I think that a "wider" link is more appropriate.  (And, indeed, it is not sufficient to just look at the counters.)